# How does Show Posts based on a keyword search work in WP_Query

Tags: wp-query, search

I am wondering how the search go through by defining 's' parameter in WP_Query.

For example if I have a post assigned to "East" term in taxonomy "Direction", the post didn't mention any "East" or "Direction" word in the post content or title. When I define the 's' value as "east" (no other parameter defined) in the WP_Query, can wp_query found the post?

Sorry for my bad English, hope you understand.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WP search is rather simplistic. After some processing on search query, it adds condition to SQL query looking for `LIKE` (contains) match in title or post content.

So natively assigned taxonomies are not searched.

So you will either have to use additional code (or third party plugin) or use third party search solution (Google Custom Search Engine is rather popular).